# Make Random String Not in Database

Tags: php, database

While writing my application, I want to provide random tags to certain entities in my database, like ABCD for example. These are always four characters, can contain uppercase letters and numbers.

The question is, how to assign them? We will never use the 1.6 million possibilities this provides, but as the database gets more full, the "seek" time for generating a random string using this L4 pseudo-code get exponentially longer:

```
function makeUniqueKey() {
    while (true) {
        $key = strtoupper(str_random(4));
        if (!DB::table('items')->where('key', '=', $key)->count()) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose this is more of an OCD curiosity question, but is there any neat trick for a non-exponential algorithm in order to create random, unique keys for items in database?

Comment: The `while` loop will eventually become infinite with a 4 character long random string. There are only so many combinations.

Comment: Yes, the execution time would approach infinity as the number of entries in the table goes to `(characters)^(string length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be to not assign them randomly. Simplest would be incremental, (e.g.: start at aaaa, all the way up to ZZZZ).

Regardless I would map this string to a number. `aaaa = 1`, `ZZZZ = 52^4`.

You could then pick a random number, and then search the database for the first gap. Should be doable with stored procedures. This should make the performance decrease at least linear, not exponential as the dataset increases.

Comment: Hmm that's an interesting solution, definitely one to consider.