# How to calculate the number of combination of a string in PHP?

Tags: php

http://www.republicof3.com/how-to-generate-unique-promotion-discount-codes-in-php/

I have found a function to generate unique promotion code in PHP

But there is a big problem, if the number of codes to be generated more then the number of remain combination(all combination-length of exclude_codes_array), the function will become infinite loop.

For example: If the $characters = "0A"; the combination are "00", "0A", "A0", "AA" = 4, if the $no_of_codes >4, the loop is cannot stopped.

So I want to check the the number of codes and all remaining combination of codes before the loop, how to calculate the combination of a string?

Comment: I ask a similar question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553515/make-random-string-not-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrete Math

```
available chars = 2 ("A", "0")
available spaces = 2 ("**")
```

chasr^spaces = 4

```
available chars = 2 ("A", "0")
available spaces = 3 ("***")
```

chars^spaces = 8

```
available chars = 3 ("A", "B", "0")
available spaces = 2 ("**")
```

chars^spaces = 9

Answer (score 2):

As per what you have calculated for A0.

```
AA, 00 , A0, 0A
```

Generalizing and using basic permutation and combination it should be ,

```
2^{strlen($str)};
```